# Python autopep8 and VS Code integration

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I currently work in an offline environment. 
I have Anaconda installed along with VS Code. 
I have downloaded and installed the MS Python Extension and the `Python-autopep8` extension. 
However, when I go to save a document and auto-format I am told that `autopep8` is not installed. 
Is there any way to get the auto-formatting to work with `autopep8`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on VS Code for Windows, and I think this might work:

1. Make sure you have it installed (in the Extension Manager).
2. Right-click your code and select `Format Document`. If a dialogue pops up that asks to install `autopep8` click `yes`.